# Boolean value not consistent w/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean

When I insert a boolean value into one table its value is `true`/`false` (primitives?), but in all other tables it is `t` and `f` as strings. Inserting the values in the same way. Why would this happen?

Using PostgreSQL with Ruby on Rails 4.

Comment: Have you read this?  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html

Comment: I have read the doc and understand they're both valid. My question is why might it be stored differently when inserting as TRUE into both tables in the same database.

Comment: It's not storing anything differently. A boolean is a boolean. It's either the same value or one isn't a boolean.

Comment: You can insert a boolean in several ways, but it's all stored the same. Check this query: SELECT 'true'::bool, true::bool, 't'::bool, '1'::bool, 1::bool;

Comment: "t" vs "true" obviously both booleans, but different values of a boolean. For some reason in ruby, if statements with the "t/f" condition are not evaluating properly is my concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyModelName.columns_hash['value']
```

revealed that my sql_type for that column was set to "character varying." Upon altering this value with a migration, the sql_type was returned to "boolean" and my literals consistently `true`/`false`.